What is the style called?
I am trying to remember the name of a style of creating things, and I cannot remember it. The resulting object tends to look like the things / beings in movies like "Mad Max" or "9".
I cannot provide a picture, because I cannot find some good keywords to lead me to it. The best I found was "art deco", but that is certainly not the "word" I am searching for.
Details:

the visual esthetics is a lot more important than function (the function can be a simple lighter);
several materials are used;
the materials are usually metal, or rather combinations of metals: steel, brass, copper - for the multitude of colors;
usually quite complex design (mostly without function) - the baroque of metal things;
the elements might move, without improving or adding function;
the details can be bent wires, pins, cogs, occasionally some glass or stone.


I finally found it!! It is called "steampunk".
Here is a picture of a lighter, where the complexity of the design does not justify the purpose, but is stunningly beautiful.


The key to Steampunk is the "technology" behind it which is a fictional combination of early (from the industrial revolution to the early 20th century) mechanics with modern (late 20C into the future) applications with an emphasis on Victorian detailing. Like steam powered airplanes or coal fired lasers.

@rebusB: your explanation is so reach and beautiful that it is almost... steampunk :)
